# How I can play any audiofile to any connected usb audio card?

Tags: linux, audio, audio-player

I have PC with linux and connected there 3 usb audio interfaces. Each audio interface has one stereo output.
I have 6 speakers connected by 2 to each stereo output.

My goal is have ability to play any sound on any card on any channel.
For example I need to play sound of beating glass on first audiocard on left channel and play some sound of nature on second audiocard on right channel.

I have looked into mpg123 but didn't found in man nothing what I want.

My prefer to have a player with next params:

```
./example_player --audio_device=1 --channel=left glass.mp3
```

If no any player with my requires please advice any python library for easy make my "example_player".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.
My prefer is mplayer. It has enought functionality for my goal.

This command:

```
$ mplayer -af channels=2:2:0:0:1:0 song1.mp3
```

will play sound on left speaker.
2 (the count of output channels) : 2 (the count of moving signal) : 0:0 (left channel route to left channel) 1:0 (right channel route to left channel)

To route sound to any audiocard you should use this command:

```
$ mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 song2.mp3
```

To see all available alsa devices use this command:

```
$ aplay -l
```

Here you'll see all available alsa devices. The first digit in 'hw' param is the card number and second digit is the device number.

Of course you can combine these both commands:

```
$ mplayer -af channels=2:2:0:0:1:0 -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 song3.mp3
```

Also I found **more useful** solution using PulseAudio!

Use thic command to list all available audiodevices with PulseAudio:

```
$ pactl list cards short
```

For example you need to output the sound to 0 card (all cards numeric begins with 0):

```
$ mplayer -ao --pulse::0 file.mp3
```

And that's works as well.